# ASP.Net: Control MainPage from iframe in ModalPopupExtander

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender, linkbutton

I have a page "Default.aspx".
In this page is a ModalPopupControl with an iFrame:

```
 <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 8px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearchGo" runat="server" Text="Jetzt suchen" OnClick="btnSearchGo_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" OkControlID="linkClosestartSeach"
                        PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" ID="mpeMiniSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="linkFooterImpressum"
                        PopupControlID="panMiniSearch">
                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:Panel Style="display: none" ID="panMiniSearch" runat="server">
                        <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                            <div class="PopupHeader" id="Div10">
                                Suche</div>
                            <div class="PopupBody">
                                <iframe id="iFrameMiniSearch" runat="server" src="MiniSearch.aspx" class="iFramePopUp">
                                </iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="popupFooter">
                                <asp:LinkButton Text="Schließen" class="linkPupopClose" runat="server" ID="linkClosestartSeach"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>



 protected void btnSearchGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iFrameMiniSearch.Attributes["src"] = "MiniSearch.aspx";
   //Do More
        mpeMiniSearch.Show();
    }
```

Now I have a LinkButton in the iFrame that should close the MPE and redirect the Page Default.aspx to Register.aspx.

Any Idea how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll need to specify a `BehaviorID` for your `ModalPopupExtender`, so you can access it from the client side. That property defaults to the `ClientID` of the extender, which will vary depending on the container chain, so it's best to specify it explicitly:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeMiniSearch" runat="server"
    BehaviorID="mpeMiniSearch" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
    OkControlID="linkClosestartSeach" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
    TargetControlID="linkFooterImpressum" PopupControlID="panMiniSearch">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Then, you can call [$find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx) from your `LinkButton`'s [ClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx) event:

```
function yourLinkButton_clientClick()
{
    var modalPopup = window.parent.$find("mpeMiniSearch");
    if (modalPopup != null) {
        modalPopup.hide();
        window.parent.location.href = "Register.aspx";
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't expect such a specific, fast and exelent working answer on such a specific question, thank you very very much!